# How to revoke a token in Discord OAuth2.0

Tags: javascript

For some reason, the code outputs status 200, but it still doesn't rework the token

cleanedToken == Token
agent = http proxy

code

```js
    try {
      const respose = await axios.post('https://discord.com/api/v8/oauth2/token/revoke', {
        client_id: "№№№№№",
        client_secret: "№№№№--№№№№№№",
        token: cleanedToken,
      }, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          Accept: 'application/json'
        },
        httpsAgent: agent
      })
  }
```

Probyval without `new URLSearchParams` without a difference it produces:

console log

```
{
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: AxiosHeaders {
    date: 'Wed, 19 Jul 2023 18:30:26 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '2',
    connection: 'close',
    'cache-control': 'no-store',
  },
  data: {}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To revoke a token in Discord OAuth2.0, you need to ensure that you are sending the correct parameters and handling the response properly. Based on your code, it seems like you are making a `POST` request to the `/oauth2/token/revoke` endpoint, which is correct. However, there are a few adjustments you can make to ensure the token revocation works as expected.

1. Use `axios.post` directly without `Promise.all`:

You don't need `Promise.all` in this case, as you are only making a single request. You can use `await` directly with `axios.post`.

2. Correct parameter names:

The Discord API expects the `token` parameter to be passed directly in the request body, not within a nested object like `new URLSearchParams`. Simply pass the `token` directly as a string.

Here's the updated code to revoke the token:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

async function revokeToken(token) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      'https://discord.com/api/v8/oauth2/token/revoke',
      `token=${token}`,
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
      }
    );

    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.response.data);
    throw error;
  }
}

// Example usage:
revokeToken('YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN');
```

Make sure to replace `'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'` with the actual access token you want to revoke. When you run the code, it should revoke the token successfully, and the response should show `{"message": "Revoked"}` if it was successful.

Remember that token revocation might take some time to propagate, and you should not rely on an immediate response from Discord's API to determine if the token is revoked. Always verify with the API if the token is still valid after the revocation attempt.